# I am Having Trouble with an if statement

Tags: javascript

I am working on an assignment and have come across an issue. I am trying to write and if, else statement. The issue is that the else statement is not being ran. Here is my work:

```
var age = "2"; //given age
var floorType = "floor"; //given floor (floor or balcony)
var floorS = "10"; 
var balconyS = "6"; 

//toddler1
if (floorType = "floor" && age <= 4) {
    print ("Floor Ticket:" + " "+ "Free"); 
} else if (floorType = "balcony" && age <=4) {
    print ("Balcony Ticket:" + " "+ "Free");
}
```

When to code is executed you can see that the else statement won't work and it just prints the data from the first if statement.

Comment: you need `==` or `===` for comparing. a single `=` is an assignment.

Comment: Use `==` instead of `=`, `==` is a logical operator and `=` is used to assigment

Comment: And your else statement wouldn't be executed anyways because `floorType` is "floor" and `age` is below 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using conditionals such as "if" and "else" statements, you need to use "===" instead of "="

"=" is assigning your variable instead of comparing.

So you code should instead be -

```
var age = "2"; //given age
var floorType = "floor"; //given floor (floor or balcony)
var floorS = "10"; 
var balconyS = "6"; 

//toddler1
if (floorType === "floor" && age <= 4) {
    print ("Floor Ticket:" + " "+ "Free"); 
} else if (floorType === "balcony" && age <=4) {
    print ("Balcony Ticket:" + " "+ "Free");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your if condition needs correction. See below.

```
var age = "2"; //given age
var floorType = "floor"; //given floor (floor or balcony)
var floorS = "10"; 
var balconyS = "6"; 

//toddler1

if (floorType === "floor" && age <= 4) {
    print ("Floor Ticket:" + " "+ "Free"); 
} else if (floorType === "balcony" && age <=4) {
    print ("Balcony Ticket:" + " "+ "Free");
}
```

You need to replace `=` with `===` or `==`.

`=` is for assignment, like when you want to assign a value to a variable.
`===` or `==` is for equality, like when you want to see if a variable is already equal to something.